# Calculate $\sin (1\pm n) \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I would like your Help to find the value of $\sin (1-n)\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sin (1+n) \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $n\geq 1$.

I am trying to find the Fourier series of a given function and I have made all my calculations correct. That is the only point that I have found difficulty.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $n$ is an integer? Just write out the first few terms till you see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate forms for both your expressions are: $\cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$, where $n$ is integer.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\sin(A+B)=\sin A \cos B+\cos A \sin B$$
$$\sin[(\pi/2 \pm n\pi/2]=\sin(\pi/2) \cos(\pm n \pi/2)+\cos(\pi/2) \sin(\pm n \pi/2)$$ $$=\cos(\pm n\pi/2)=\cos(n\pi/2)=0, ~if~ n=2m+1, =(-1)^m, ~if~ n=2m.$$
Here $m \in I$.